# Get JSON from tables of Mysql using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, reference

I'm trying to build a JSON output to get the specific client invoices using PHP, but I'm not able to get the results correctly.

This is the result of my query

```
[
{
    "CLIENT": "CLIENTN1",
    "CODE": "51301",
    "TOTAL": "38.360000",
    "INVOICENUMBER": 2976,
    "PRODUCTNAME": "PRODUCT 1",
    "QUANTITY": 3,
    "PRODUCTID": 1,
    "DATE": 2020/12/02
},
{
    "CLIENT": "CLIENTN1",
    "CODE": "51302",
    "TOTAL": "38.360000",
    "INVOICENUMBER": 2976,
    "PRODUCTNAME": "PRODUCT 2",
    "QUANTITY": 4,
    "PRODUCTID": 5,
    "DATE": 2020/12/02
},
{
     "CLIENT": "CLIENTN1",
    "CODE": "51303",
    "TOTAL": "50.360000",
    "INVOICENUMBER": 2991,
    "PRODUCTNAME": "PRODUCT 3",
    "QUANTITY": 10,
    "PRODUCTID": 8,
    "DATE": 2020/12/02
}]
```

I'd like to get this JSON format

```
{
"CLIENTN1": [
    {
        "2976": {
            "DATE": 2020/12/02,
            "TOTAL": "38.360000",
            "PRODUCTS": {
                "PRODUCT 1": {
                    "QUANTITY": 3,
                    "PRODUCTID": 1
                },
                "PRODUCT 2": {
                    "QUANTITY": 4,
                    "PRODUCTID": 5
                }
            }
        },
        "2991": {
            "DATE": 2020/12/02,
            "TOTAL": "50.360000",
            "PRODUCTS": {
                "PRODUCT 3": {
                    "QUANTITY": 10,
                    "PRODUCTID": 8
                }
            }
        }
    }
] }
```

I've done this code, but I'm not sure why it does not work. In this case, I'm only one client for testing, but in the database I have almost 10,000 records,
so I think it is very complicated work this way, and I was thinking to group this data in this JSON format.

```php
for($i =0; $i < count($variable);$i++){
    for($j =0; $j < count($variable)-1;$j++){

    if( $variable[$i]['CLIENT'] ==  $variable[$j+1]['CLIENT']){
    if( $variable[$i]['DATE'] ==  $variable[$j+1]['DATE']){
        if( $variable[$i]['INVOICENUMBER'] ==  $variable[$j+1]['INVOICENUMBER']){

            $dataproducts = array("QUANTITY"=>$variable[$i]['QUANTITY'],"PRODUCTID"=>$variable[$i 
            ['PRODUCTID']);
            $products = array($variable[$i]['PRODUCTNAME'] =>$dataproducts);
            $datainvoice = array("PRODUCTS"=>$products,"TOTAL"=>$variable[$i]['TOTAL']);
            $invoices = array($variable[$i]['INVOICENUMBER']=>$datainvoice);
            $client = array($variable[$i]['CLIENT'] => $invoices);
      
        
        }else{
        
        
        }
       }else{
 
       }
  

     }else{


     }
}
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with MySQL or REST. You might be using those features elsewhere in your application. You might be fetching the JSON data from MySQL, or returning the data in a REST response, but that's not relevant to this question. I'm removing those tags from your question.

Comment: Your question also doesn't seem to have anything to do with Firebird.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not valid.
You must add double quotes to date like this
...
"DATE": "2020/12/02"
...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer your question, but I think there's a few coding tips which would make your time much, much easier.

The first is, I never permit developers who I manage to use variable names $i or $j. I know, you see it everywhere, in all the textbooks, etc. Don't do it! Name them properly. What are they?

The problem is that your query is building a flatter result, whereas you're looking for a many-layered result.

Without knowing what $i and $j represent, or what the variable name of the result of the query is, it's hard, but instead of:

$result[] = $input[$i]

You'd want something like

$result[$i['CLIENTNAME']][] = $input[$i]

This is because you want to add an array of the clients which then contains their orders, not just an array of orders. Multi layered :)

Comment: When the variable scope is very short, there's no need to name it like a word. Scope of For-loop i and j are very trivial and tiny. Why would you micromanage there. Watch "Uncle Bob"s Clean Coding series to see why it is so.

Comment: Because code grows, and clarity prevents many a bug.